# Can micronaut log access logs with logback?

Tags: logback, micronaut

I'm trying to setup access-logs in micronaut, but, as logback-access library uses a servlet filter, I don't see a straight-forward way to do it.
Is there a different solution? Some hidden Micronaut config or a trustable adapter of the filter (A Micronaut Filter wrapper for Servlet filters would be great)

Comment: Micronaut is not a servlet, and thus servlet filters cannot be used. The feature you're looking for really is a feature for Netty (the underlying http server), and would apply to any library/framework that is using Netty for http

Comment: I know it cannot be used as is, but maybe with a wrapper, as Filters are interfaces. I don't need it generic, I need it to use with micronaut, so, micronaut filters can be used, I just didn't want to write the filter myself.

Answer (score 4):

The Micronaut http server supports automatically adding a `LoggingHandler`, you have to supply `micronaut.server.netty.logLevel: <<level>>` in your configuration where `level` is one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR. I don't know if that will provide the same detail that logback-access does, but you can give it a try.

EDIT: Be sure to also configure a logger. For example in logback:

`<logger name="io.netty.handler.logging" level="TRACE"/>`

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that: btw, I think it is `io.micronaut.http.server.netty`, and is fragmented and not complete.

Comment: @leoconco See my edit - make sure you have the logger configured

Comment: I just wrote my own filter, and used a custom Logger name, way easier @james-kleeh

Comment: @JamesKleeh is this able to see outbound request/response?

Comment: I assume this answer applies to Micronaut 1, as version 2+ has some [configuration properties for Netty access logger](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.0/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.http.server.netty.configuration.NettyHttpServerConfiguration$AccessLogger)

Answer (score -1):

I used the mn CLI to create my application (using groovy as the language for my development), and mn code generated a trivial logback.xml. from the 1st time I ran my application, logging was working.

Here's what was generated OOTB:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Then I went to the logback home page and used its [code generator](https://logback.qos.ch/translator/asGroovy.html) to convert the mn seed xml file to logback.groovy.

here's the result, after I added my logger for the hello.world package.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
//
// Built on Sun Jul 07 02:41:38 CEST 2019 by logback-translator
// For more information on configuration files in Groovy
// please see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html

// For assistance related to this tool or configuration files
// in general, please contact the logback user mailing list at
//    http://qos.ch/mailman/listinfo/logback-user

// For professional support please see
//   http://www.qos.ch/shop/products/professionalSupport
// ----------------------------------------------------------

import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
    withJansi = true
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n"
    }
}
root(INFO, ["STDOUT"])
logger("hello.world", DEBUG)
```